# Pass $scope through ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I know there are lot of questions same as this which have been answered but it is a kind of different.

```
<div ng-repeat="hello in hello track by $index">
<div ng-click="data($index)">
{{data}}
</div>
</div>


$scope.data = function($index) {
  $scope.sweet = $index;
  console.log($scope.sweet);
}
```

I am passing a value through `ng-click` and I am getting in controller too. 
But when I am passing it using `$scope` then its value is only available in the same view where the `ng-click` has been used not in other views.
regards.

Comment: What are we supposed to do with this code? Can you share the code that doesn't work?

Comment: I do not see `ng-repeat` anywhere.. Is it there ?

Comment: sorry I can't show you but here I can't get $scope.sweet's value in html like when I use {{sweet}} in html I get nothing

Comment: @rayon I have edited my code.

Comment: $index works only into ng-repeat, you cant use it in that way.

Comment: the 'data' into ng-repeat should be an array, you confuse array with function.

Comment: I have just used a demo here. In actual code I have used different name for each one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atula, We have many ways to pass the value from one function to other function or controller , Like : save value in some **global varables**, Save the Value in **$rootscope**, or save value in the **localstorege** of angularjs

So i think the simple ways is to save the value in the $rootScrop

```
$scope.data = function($index) {
 $rootScope.sweet = $index;
 console.log($scope.sweet);
}
```

You need to define **$rootScope** in **controler** to access this:
Now call this where you wants to access the index value of this function

```
 alert( $rootScope.sweet);
```

It will show alert of your value.
I hope it will solve your problem .
Have a happy code life

Comment: It my responsibility to help other,

Answer (score 0):

That's because the $scope object is local to the view. You can refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_scopes.asp) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">
<div ng-click="getItem($index,item)">
{{item}}
</div>
</div>
```

**into controller:**

```
$scope.data = [{sweet:something},{sweet:somethingelse}];
$scope.sweet='';
$scope.sweetIndx='';
$scope.getItem = function($index,item) {
  $scope.sweetIndx = $index;//so you get the index into the array
  $scope.sweet = item;//you also get the name of the item
  console.log($scope.sweet);
}
```

Comment: why pass $index in to function in controller?

Comment: really my ng-repeat working all correct I don't need to edit anything in that. My REAL problem is that {{sweet}} is only available in the same view where is have used ng-click not in other views..